# How to show bar on the top of other bar in bar chart of mp chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Hi I want to draw a Bar chart like this

[image]

As Shown in picture I want to draw two bars of different sizes at same place, Is it possible to develop something like this using [MpAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) Library? if yes then how.

Comment: you can install already made example from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxmassdeveloper.mpchartexample to check all available type of charts options.

Comment: Haven't find anything like this, Is there have any way by which I can Modify any of chart and achieve this?

Comment: You have to modify onDraw method in MPChart